# Windows Live Mail: Order of Evaluation for Junk Filter and Message Rules

Tags: outlook.com

Are message rules evaluated before the junk filters? I want to be sure that all messages that meet particular criteria are sent to a folder fpr checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, message rules in Windows Live Mail are executed prior to reaching the Junk Filter. This allows you to bypass the Junk filter altogether using rules:

[image]